# Is it possible to update the store outside of the Provider context in Redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

I have some configuration settings I want to set and save to redux store before my main app loads. This is so that all the children components already have the configuration data pre-loaded and they can read it from the store using `redux-connect`.

For now, I only know how to use and update the store inside my connected components that are wrapped in the Provider context.

Is there a way to update it outside of that?

For example:

```
class App extends React {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      // UPDATE REDUX STORE HERE
   }

   componentDidUpdate() {
      // OR UPDATE REDUX STORE HERE
   }

   render() {
       return (
           <Provider store={store}>
              <Child />
           </Provider>
       );
   }
 }
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: Forget about React for a moment. Redux doesn't have anything to do with React (that's a special-purpose library; `react-redux`)! It's just Javascript. You need to read this: https://redux.js.org/api/api-reference

Answer (score 2):

`store` is just an object which contains `dispatch` and `getState` functions. This means that wherever the store is accessible outside of the application, you can manipulate it using these attributes.

```
const store = configureStore();

const App = () => (<Provider store={store} />);

store.dispatch({ type: SOME_ACTION_TYPE });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can call the Provider outside of `App` Component in `index.js`

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App/>
    </Provider>

    , document.getElementById('root'));
```

now in your App class it's possile add a `connect` or an `updateAction`

```
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import {updateStuf} from "./actions/projectActions";



class App extends Component {
    componentWillMount() {
        this.props.updateStuf();
    }

    render() {
        const {stuff} = this.props;
        return (
                <div className="stuff">

                </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        stuff: state.project.stuff
    }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, {updateStuf})(App);
```